# Should CSS filters be applied before or after overflow:hidden?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, safari, overflow

If I apply `filter: blur()` and `overflow: hidden` to an element, which should be applied first? The behaviour is different in Safari compared to Firefox and Chrome. In Firefox and Chrome, you get the following (filter is applied after overflow: hidden):

[image: Firefox and Chrome]

Whereas in Safari, the content is clipped after applying the filter:

[image: Safari]

I am unable to work out from the relevant specifications which is the correct behaviour. Which is correct according to the specification, or is it unspecified?

```css
.container {
    padding: 20px;
}

.box {
    filter: blur(10px);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: teal;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```